# Laravel Task Scheduler Error appendOutputTo

Tags: laravel-5.1

I added following line in `Console/Kernal`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->appendOutputTo($filePath);
}
```

Then in cmd prompt I ran the following artisan command to run the scheduled tasks but I get following error

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::appendOutputTo()
```

Where as when I use `->sendOutputTo($filename)` instead it works fine, of course it doesn't append but overwrite a file.

Thanks,

K

Comment: May I ask why you are using the Task Scheduler to run the queue? Why not use Supervisor for this? Regarding your question: The only thing I could find was this link to the manual http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#task-output. In the note they mentioned  the following: Note: The emailOutputTo and sendOutputTo methods are exclusive to the command method and are not supported for call.

Comment: @ThomasSnijder I think I used task scheduler because I wanted the scheduling logic sub-versioned in my laravel itself. Why do you think we cannot/shouldn't use the task scheduler to run the queue?

Comment: Queues are normally used for just handling time consuming task that don't need to be executed right away, like sending an email. You can easily delay that for like 30 to 60 seconds. Task are used for repeated operations on a fixed moment like cleaning a database table or something else. I just want to let you know you could run queues with Supervisor and that you don't need Task scheduler to do this. But if you want to do it with Task scheduler  i don't think there are any draw backs.

Comment: Another idea. If you really want to append the output of your queue to a file. Maybe you can build this logic in to your queue job? So you don't need to use the appendOutputTo method.

Comment: @ThomasSnijder I didn't understand *The emailOutputTo and sendOutputTo methods are exclusive to the command method and are not supported for call* , What do they mean by 'call'? And I am sure you noticed that I used the exact same code as mentioned in doc. page. I can try creating a queue job. (So looks like its a bug that appendOutputTo does not exist, Right?)

Comment: Call is used in task scheduling like a function. And command is used to actually execute a command on the command line. There are examples in the documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling. I don't know if it is a bug. But I would expect you could use the appendOutputTo method on a command cause it is almost the same as sendOutputTo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I was right, appendOutputTo() isn't present in Laravel 5.1.

Good news is it will be available in Laravel 5.2

[laravel-news-5.2-whats-coming](https://laravel-news.com/2015/11/laravel-5-2-a-look-at-whats-coming/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Vol%202%20Issue%2026&utm_content=Vol%202%20Issue%2026%20CID_b9c6ba11709d57ce3e635ed936b8b5e3&utm_source=email%20marketing&utm_term=Read%20Now)

**Update:** 10-Dec-2015
as sstarlight mentioned, and I rechecked (searched for appendOutputTo function), and yes it is now present in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php` unlike before.
Thanks laravel and thanks sstarlight to let us know.

Comment: FYI, i use appendOutputTo at laravel 5.1 and it's working perfectly. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#task-output see the documentation. $filePath > do you define it?

Comment: you can update to the latest version of laravel 5.1 and the function will be there if you do not want to move totally to laravel 5.2 for whatever reasons

Comment: You are right and this is since Dec last year. They patched v5.1 last year in December, that's what my Update meant.