# why isn't "between" available in a laravel schedule task?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've got the manual in front of me, I've searched Google, and nothing. Why is this:

```
//update combined results cache
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\CombinedYieldUpdater@index')
            ->everyFiveMinutes()
            ->between('02:00', '04:00');
```

causing this?

```
[2017-01-09 11:42:02] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::between()
```

Comment: You're trying to run a command, not a callback, so shouldn't it be `$schedule->command(...)` instead?

Comment: Makes no difference @JoelHinz exact same error message

Comment: It looks like you don't use Laravel 5.3. Similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33384897/5139222) where user wanted to use method available in Laravel 5.2. and he was using 5.1. Are you sure you using 5.3?

Comment: You are entirely right @KuKeC, after months of being told it's on 5.3 it is in fact on 5.1. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @gedq Glad to help you. I'v added my comment as answer

Comment: Please let us see the full method you are using in order to comment correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't use Laravel 5.3. Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384897/laravel-task-scheduler-error-appendoutputto) where user wanted to use method available in Laravel 5.2. and he was using 5.1.

Are you sure you using 5.3? If not update your framework to 5.3 and it should work.